# Zend_Uri_Http generates "inet_pton(): Unrecognized address" error

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework, xml-rpc

In our application, the backend is accessed via `Zend_XmlRpc`. In the backend, I'm using `Zend_Http_Client` together with `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl` to connect to another web service over HTTPS.

During unit tests, everything works as expected and the remote service is accessible. But when the frontend connects via `Zend_XmlRpc` to the backend and causes the backend to do the exact same thing like the unit tests do, I get the following error:

`inet_pton(): Unrecognized address test.example.com#0` (url changed)

This is caused by `Zend_Validate_Ip->isValid('test.example.com')`.

The only difference I can spot is the additional frontend-backend-connection which is also using Zend components for communicating. Everything else is the same.

Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a resolver issue in the server and zf isn't catching it beforehand. It's getting a hostname where it should be getting an IP address (obviously), and it can't convert a string to a binary IP address

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in Zend_Validate that was fixed with release 1.9.